# Issue returning NSURL in Swift

Tags: swift, oauth, nsurl

Alright folks, I'm trying to write a segment that formats a NSURL from `NSDictionary` parts for an OAuth 2.0 authentication body. The issue is that I cannot return the NSURL that I generate.

```
private func formAuthURL ((Void) -> NSURL)
{
    // Declare the base part of the URL:
    var AuthURLString : String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";

    // Now, space-delimit the scopes and redirect URL - this works by replacing " " with "%20"
    // and others in accordance with standard URL practice:
    self.AuthScope    = self.AuthScope?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString (" ", withString: "%20", options: nil, range: nil);
    self.AuthScope = self.AuthScope?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString (":", withString: "%3A", options: nil, range: nil);
    self.AuthScope = self.AuthScope?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString ("/", withString: "%2F", options: nil, range: nil);
    self.AuthRedirect = self.AuthRedirect?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString (":", withString: "%3A", options: nil, range: nil);
    self.AuthRedirect = self.AuthRedirect?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString ("/", withString: "%2F", options: nil, range: nil);

    // Now, format the Client ID and other variables into parts:
    let loc_ClientID = "client_id=\(self.ClientID)";
    let loc_Redirect = "redirect_uri=\(self.AuthRedirect)";
    let other_parts  = "response_type=code&access_type=offline";

    // Combine, format into URL, and return:
    AuthURLString    = AuthURLString + loc_ClientID + loc_Redirect + self.AuthScope! + other_parts;
    var AuthURL      = NSURL (string: AuthURLString);
    return AuthURL;
}
```

I've also tried concatenating the return statement (i.e. `return NSURL (string: AuthURLString)` to no avail. The error it generates is as follows:

`Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSURL?' to type '()'`.

I'm dead stumped on what this error means. It seems like some sort of optional, but I've tried changing the function return type (that is, `((Void) -> NSURL?)` and I still can't get it to work. The whole concept of optionals and unwrapping and what not is something I still don't grasp very well, so if this is a primitive question, forgive me.

Comment: You may also want to look at [NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html). NSHipster also has a nice [article](http://nshipster.com/nsurl/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
private func formAuthURL ((Void) -> NSURL)
```

With this:

```
private func formAuthURL() -> NSURL
```

---

Here is the basic form of function declarations in swift:

```
func functionName(paramName:ParamType) -> ReturnType
```

Based on this you can see that your function was trying to take a closure with the form `(Void) -> NSURL` and returns nothing (if you don't give a return type using `-> ReturnType` it assumes you return nothing).

You can read more about functions in swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).